# Change size PDF unproportionally by Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, printing, resize, ghostscript

I have PDF document with many pages 595x420 ppi but I need this pages push in 595x210 but all text must be visible.

So.. Can I change scale of PDF pages unproportionally (no zoom) to fit custom size of page with ghostscript or I must to use some another program?

Comment: How do you plan to fit all the text from a 595x420 page onto a page half the size without altering the scale ?

Comment: I know that ratio must be changed because I need fill page with content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want scaling applied to one axis and not the other, then you will have to do some PostScript programming. In /ghostpdl/Resource/Init/pdf_main.ps is the code which calculates the matrix required:

```
/pdf_PDF2PS_matrix {    % <pdfpagedict> -- matrix
  matrix currentmatrix matrix setmatrix exch
  % stack: savedCTM <pdfpagedict>
  dup get_any_box
  % stack: savedCTM <pdfpagedict> /Trim|Crop|Art|MediaBox <Trim|Crop|Art|Media Box>
  oforce_elems normrect_elems fix_empty_rect_elems 4 array astore
  //systemdict /PDFFitPage known {
    PDFDEBUG { (Fiting PDF to imageable area of the page.) = flush } if
```

That code calculates the x and y scale values and makes them the same. If you want them to differ, that's what you will have to modify. Note you will also have to set a specific media size using `-dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS` and `-dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS` and set `-dFIXEDMEDIA` to prevent the PDF file resizing the media.

Comment: Thanks but this is higher level than I know do now. Can you tell me something more about this solution? I found pdf_main.ps file with this code but still I don't know what I should change.

Comment: You're going to need to understand the PostScript language to make any useful changes here. PostScript uses a matrix method to map user space to device space, and this function calculates a new CTM where the x and y scale factors are chosen to be the same, and the minimum distance from 1,1. You will presumably want to calculate the minimum x or y required to scale the media and then set whichever is the smallest change.

Comment: Thank you! Only one line I need to add for scale to my size `1 .5 scale`. This site helped me more understand PS language http://www.mefco.com/psc/